# preg_match_all from array php and input form

Tags: php, arrays, search, input, preg-match-all

Hi I want to search form using preg_match_all.
Why it needed?
I have DB that having two fields 'id' and 'text'. I must to search some text from this DB with rules like `..a...`, `a..a..` and etc.
I tried so many ways I am a newby on php and programming that's why I can not solve this problem. Please help me solve it.
My code is below.
I have HTML form, which having one input field named 'subject' and one button.
When I wrote something to input field like `a...a..` array must be shown below.
For example I have words stored at DB:

1. apple
2. apricots
3. avocado
4. bananas
5. blueberries
6. blackberries

I want to search using mask like: `ap....` / result must be: `apple`, `apricots`
Or: `.....berri...` / result: `blueberries`, `blackberries`

```
        $infotext = $_GET['subject']; //this is string from input form
        $query = "SELECT * FROM baza LIMIT 100";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
         while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
         {
             $search = preg_match_all("/$infotext/", $row['text']); }
             mysqli_free_result($result);

        print_r($search);
```

Comment: What is not working?Please, edit your question and add some examples of `text` and `$infotext` with expected results.

Comment: You have edited the code, good. But the first question is: "what is not working?" Also, what are these dots in the mask, where do they come from? Are they relevant? Does each dot stands for a character? If so, `ap....` doesn't match `apple` (One extra dot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved. Thanks for everyone who tryed to help me. Specally @andreys-scherbakov.
The solved code is.

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM baza WHERE text REGEXP '$infotext'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            print_r($row['text'].'<br/>');
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If a dot in a mask stands for an arbitrary symbol, you already have a regular expression in hand. So you may use them to search in your DB:

"SELECT * FROM baza WHERE text **REGEXP** '$infotext' LIMIT 100"

Of course you should have user provided strings prepared as previously mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of fetching unnecessary results. You can do this using query also

```
"SELECT * FROM baza WHERE text LIKE '%'.$infotext.'%' LIMIT 100".
```

(**Do this using prepared statements to prevent from sql injection.**)

And then you can get this result in array.

```
 while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
       $search[] =  $row['text']; 
  }
  mysqli_free_result($result);

  print_r($search);
```

Comment: This is not worked. I want to search using text mask from whole DB.

Comment: @HayrullaMelibayev check my edited answer. you are getting your desired result or not

Comment: this way is not that which I looking.
I want to search using mask the operator LIKE can not find with mask.
LIKE operator can give result some part of words but I want to search like this **a..e....**
And resul must be: append, appendix

Comment: Ok. then in your question are you not getting array using $search[] = preg_match_all("/$infotext/", $row['text']); }